# Difference between 記憶 and 記憶力

Tags: word-choice

What is the difference between 記憶 and 記憶力? I guess latter is more like 'power of recollection'. Are both the following sentences equally natural?

> 彼は記憶力がいい。
> 彼は記憶がいい。
> He has a good memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

記憶 refers to memory in the sense of remembered things, whereas 記憶力 refers to the ability to remember things.

If "He has a good memory" means "He is good at remembering things", 彼は記憶力がいい is the only natural choice. If the sentence means "He remembers some good thing (e.g. about this place)", it would be 彼には(この場所について)いい記憶がある or 彼にはいい思い出がある. If the sentence means "He owns a good (USB) memory", it would be 彼はいい(USB)メモリを持っている.

Comment: As a standalone sentence "He has a good memory" could only ever mean "He is good at remembering things", but the other options are good to know too. Thanks.

Comment: `He owns a good (USB) memory` 笑た